# Displaying Custom Taxonomy List Posts By Slug?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, categories

Is it possible to list the posts from a custom taxonomy by slug along?

This link kind of does it but i want to target the slugs rather than just the whole taxonomy itself

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Display_Terms_in_a_custom_taxonomy

So i have Custom Taxonomy 'Books' within that i have Book 1 and Book 2.

I want to list all the posts attached to Book 1 and then separately all the posts attached to Book 2 ideally.

Possible?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have registered your custom taxonomy to with `'rewrite' => true`, then WordPress should automatically build taxonomy archives for you at yousite.com/{taxonomy base}/{term slug}.

There are a lot of caveats and problems that can arise, but for simple setups, this works like a charm. To find the right URL, go to (I'm guessing a little here) Posts > Books and then click "View" beneath the "Book 1" taxonomy.